# How to compile reaver-wps with msys on windows?

Tags: windows, compilation, mingw, msys

im trying to compile reaver-wps ( https://code.google.com/p/reaver-wps/ ) on windows 7 using MSYS. I know there's only support for linux builds but i just wanted to give it a try.
What i did so far: install and compile http://www.winpcap.org/devel.htm, compile sqlite3

ran $ ./configure *in src forlder of reaver-wps*

ran $ make

which failed:

```
$ make
> (cd utils && make)
make[1]: Entering directory `/f/temp/reaver/src/utils'
make[1]: cc: Command not found
make[1]: *** [base64.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/f/temp/reaver/src/utils'
make[1]: *** [libutils] Error 2
```

did someone manage to compile it on win? if yes please tell me how. thanks for any tips / hints you have!

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that you don't have a C compiler installed *or* that the installed C compiler is not available through a command `cc` in your PATH. It's not surprising that this is a showstopper for building a C program.

If you have GCC installed, you can maybe fix this by creating a symlink from `cc` to `gcc` in your `bin` directory.

Answer (score -1):

install cygwin it contains gcc for win and the compile using it.It is a free tool that downloads libraries from internet.